AspectJ and PicoCLI does not populate properties as expected
I'm creating an annotation to attach an Aspect that would take care of authenticating an user before running a CLI command in my Spring Boot app.
Here are the components:
// The annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Authenticated {}

// The aspec
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
class AuthenticatedAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(com.menighin.picoclijava.annotation.Authenticated)")
    public Object doAuthentication(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}

// The PicoCLI command
@Component
@Command(name = "testing", description = "Testing command")
public class TestingCommandJava implements Runnable {

    @Option(
        names = {"-ci", "--creator-initials"},
        description = "The initials of the creator",
        required = true
    )
    private String creatorInitials;

    // setters and getters

    @Override
    @Authenticated
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hi!");
    }
}

// The boot app
@SpringBootApplication
public class PicoclijavaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private TestingCommandJava testingCommand;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PicoclijavaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        var cmd = new CommandLine(testingCommand);
        cmd.execute(args);
    }
}

Before going further into the implementation itself Im already facing the issue where the creatorInitials are not set when I have the aspect run.
Checking this and this answers by @kriegaex my understanding is this happens because:

The aspect creates a CGLIB proxy of my TestingCommand (I can verify this debugging)
PicoCLI then populates by reflection those parameters onto the proxy instead of the underlaying object (I can actually see the property set on the proxy instance)
When I finally get to my method, those fields are not set

So my questions are:

Is my understanding correct?
Is there anything I can do (besides changing PicoCLI code and opening a PR) to get those fields populated into my underlaying object rather than the proxy?

Thanks!

I do not know PicoCLI. Does it have no other mode than using reflection? Using setter injection, maybe? Why is your command a Spring component? Is that really necessary? Does the command semantically belong to your application's object model? If so, you could still put the PicoCLI options into a value object accessed by the component. BTW, there are non-reflective way to fetch a Spring proxy's target object. I.e., there are several ways you can solve this. It would be interesting to play with a little reproducer, if you care to publish one on GitHub. That would be better than theorising.

I quickly copied your code and also checked PicoCLI's manual section about Spring Boot. It explicitly warns about the dynamic proxy situation and recommends setter injection:

Your source code mentions, that you have getters and setters anyway, so you can just move the annotation onto the setter:
  @Option(
    names = { "-ci", "--creator-initials" },
    description = "The initials of the creator",
    required = true
  )
  public void setCreatorInitials(String creatorInitials) {
    this.creatorInitials = creatorInitials;
  }

Now, it works flawlessly without any ugly reflection in the aspect.

Well, one way I found of doing that was to manually copy the fields set into the proxy class down to the underlying class using reflection on my Aspect JointPoint. Open to other ideas.
